# Can I save sitemap.xml file in other domain?

Tags: domains, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have 2 domain. Domain No.1 contains a sitemap index: `http://example1.com/sitemap-index.xml` with content like this:

```
<sitemapindex>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://example1.com/0.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-11-23</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://example1.com/1.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-11-23</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

And domain No.2 contains sitemaps (`http://example2.com/0.xml`, `http://example2.com/1.xml`, ...). I will submit `http://example1.com/sitemap-index.xml` to Google Webmaster Tools. Normally, I will save sitemap files to same domain but this time, I want to save sitemap files to the other domain? Will Google allow this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you explain more? As it is, what you are trying to do is rather unclear. I am not sure of the purpose of cross-referencing like you seem to want.

Comment: Hello, I edited the question @closetnoc !